# CKEditor ambitious scrolling

Tags: php, ckeditor

I have a problem with CKEditor. I have table in table and in that table I have ckeditor. When I press enter it scroll my page to the bottom. I noticed that this is happening because of fields above ckeditor. Those fields are resizable, so that is one source of the issue. And I'm sure that someone else have same problem. I didn't paste the code here because my page has 935 rows. Does anyone knows how to fix this?

UPDATE: This is short version of code

```
<html>
<body>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
    <td class="achtergrond2" height="45" align="center" class="toptitel">Ticket title</td>
</tr>
<tr><td align="center">Here goes errors or confirmations</td></tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <table width="98%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
            <tr>
                <td valign="top">
                    <form name="pdf" action="pdf_werkbon.php" target="_blank" method="GET" style="margin-bottom:0; margin-top:10px;" accept-charset="UTF-8">
                        <a colspan="3" class="achtergrond2" valign="top"><a href="#" class="standaard" onClick="JavaScript: Verstuur2(forms[0], '1');">  <img src="../images/print_printer.png" border="0">Hand-out</a>
                         <span style="position:aboslute; float:right;"><a href="../index_account.php?id=id;?>&submenu=32" target="_blank" class="standaard" >  <img src="../img/customers.png" border="0">Account</a></span><br/><br/>
                        <input type="hidden" value="" name="id_tic">
                        <input type="hidden" value=".pdf" name="ext">
                    </form>
                    <form name="pdf" action="pdf_prestatiebon.php" target="_blank" method="GET" style="margin-bottom:0; margin-top:10px;" accept-charset="UTF-8">
                        <a href="#" class="standaard" onClick="//Some javascript function JavaScript: Verstuur2(forms[0], '1');"><img src="../images/print_printer.png" border="0">Prestatiebon</a>
                        <input type="hidden" value="id_tic_value" name="id_tic">
                        <input type="hidden" value=".pdf" name="ext">
                    </form>
                    <form name="form1" action="detail.php?id=someid&id_tic=id_tic_value&submenu=submenu&nc=time&nc=time=time" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="UTF-8">
                        <input type="hidden" value="somedata" name="historiekgegevens" />
                                <input type="hidden" value="status_value" name="status" />
                                <input type="hidden" value="logon_value" name="logon" />
                                <input type="hidden" value="value" name="TotWerkuren" />
                                <input type="hidden" value="product_value" name="Product" />
                        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
                          <tr><td>Name</td><td>Value</td></tr>
                          <tr><td>Title</td><td><input type="text" name="title" value="TITLE"></td></tr>
                          <tr><td>Category:</td><td><select><option>Here I have a select type filled with data from database</option></select></td></tr>
                          <tr><td>Classification:</td><td><select><option>(same as above - some data from database)Here I have a select type filled with data from database</option></select></td></tr>
                          <tr><td>Project:</td><td><select><option>(same as above - some data from database)Here I have a select type filled with data from database</option></select></td></tr>
                          <tr><td>Service:</td><td><select><option>(same as above - some data from database)Here I have a select type filled with data from database</option></select></td></tr>
                          <tr><td>Company name:</td><td><input type="radio" name="company" value="yes">Our company&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="company" value="no">Not our company</td></tr>
                          <tr><td>Customer:</td><td>name of the customer</td></tr>
                          <tr><td>User:</td><td><select><option>Here I have a select type filled with data from database -users names</option></select></td></tr>
                          <tr><td>CC:</td><td><select name="cc[]" multiple="multiple" size="3"><option>Users names and email addresses</option><option>John Doe(john.doe@mail.com)</option><option>John Doe(john.doe@mail.com)</option></select></td></tr>
                          <tr><td>Order:</td><td><select><option>(same as above - some data from database)Here I have a select type filled with data from database</option></select></td></tr>
                          <tr><td>Description:</td><td>Description of the problem that need to be solved</td></tr>
                          <tr><td>Planned work:</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="plan">
                                  <input type="text" value="" name="plandate">
                              <script language="JavaScript">
                                    /*TIGRA CALENDAR - Not source of problem. I removed it, and problem exist.
                                     new tcal ({
                                            'formname': 'form1',
                                            'controlname': 'plandate'
                                    });*/
                                    </script>
                              Start time: <select name="starthours"><option>Here is print hours from 0 to 23</option></select> : <select name="starthours"><option>Here I print minutes (0,15,30,45)</option></select>
                              End time: <select name="endhours"><option>Here is print hours from 0 to 23</option></select> : <select name="endhours"><option>Here I print minutes (0,15,30,45)</option></select><br/>
                              <select name="employees[]" multiple="multiple" size="3"><option>Users names and email addresses</option><option>John Doe(john.doe@mail.com)</option><option>John Doe(john.doe@mail.com)</option></select>
                              <select name="departments[]" multiple="multiple" size="3"><option>Two departments</option><option value="support@mail.com">support</option><option value="development@mail.com">development</option></select>
                              </td></tr>
                            <tr><td>Ticket owners:</td><td>
                                    Date: <input type="text" value="" name="datuminput">
                              <script language="JavaScript">
                                    /*TIGRA CALENDAR - Not source of problem. I removed it, and problem exist.
                                     new tcal ({
                                            'formname': 'form1',
                                            'controlname': 'plandate'
                                    });*/
                                    </script>
                                <table>
                                    <tr><th>Name</th><th>From (hh:mm)</th><th>To (hh:mm)</th><th>Tariffs</th><th>Total</th></tr>
                                    <tr><th>John Doe</th><th><select><option>hours</option></select>:<select><option>minutes</option></select></th><th><select><option>hours</option></select>:<select><option>minutes</option></select></th><th><select><option>hours</option></select>:<select><option>wich department employee belong</option></select></th><th>Total hours worked on ticket</th></tr>
                                </table>
                                </td></tr>
                <tr>
                              <td class="standaard" valign="top">Description:</td>
                                <td colspan="2">
                  <textarea id="Omschrijving" name="Omschrijving" cols="50"></textarea>
                   <script type="text/javascript">
                      CKEDITOR.replace('Omschrijving');
                   </script>
               <span class="standaard">*</span>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td class="oke8" valign="top">Internal Update(ITAF):</td>
               <td colspan="2">
                   <textarea id="ITAF" name="ITAF" cols="50"></textarea>
                   <script type="text/javascript">
                      CKEDITOR.replace('ITAF');
                   </script>
               </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
           </td>
           </tr>
           </table>
       <!-- Here I load another table with history of updates inserted through ck editor -->
        </td>
           </tr>
           </table>
```

SOLUTION: 
I have this worked out. Actually it was a stupid problem. I add 
    `<!DOCTYPE html>`
above `<html>` and it's working. I didn't check this cause I didn't create this page, and this was working without `<!DOCTYPE html>` on Firefox before update on version 21.

Comment: why don't post your HTML code too? You also can use jsfiddle.net .

Comment: On second thought, you're right. I'll post the code short version of my code as soon as I finish it. I'm preparing it for dev.ckeditor

Comment: I can't use jsfiddle.net cause I can't include all code from ckeditor to jsfiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually this was very stupid problem. Page haven't had `<!DOCTYPE html>` and as soon as I put it, it started to work normally.

Comment: Had the same issue across multiple versions of CKE, this fixed it.